# How to set DISPLAY variable for a process?

Tags: environment-variables, postgresql

I try to run pgadmin3 as user postgres and I get following error:

```
No protocol specified
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

Command `pgadmin3` runs well under pavel (my main user account).

The answers of [a question on this](https://askubuntu.com/q/4444/338446) suggested either some server connection magic (not my case - I try to run it on localhost), or setting DISPLAY variable. I checked it through printenv both under pavel and postgres, and it's :0 for both. I used [the trick to find which processes have DISPLAY variable set](https://askubuntu.com/a/432611/338446) under both users. For pavel, there's very long list with the DISPLAY values :0 (for most processes, including pgadmin) or :0.0 (for some). But for postgres, there are just three or four processes in the list.

Here's where I'm stuck: **how to set an environment variable** (DISPLAY, in this case) **for a process?** Or better, for application/user combination, so that the process would see the DISPLAY setting from the very start. I already tried to hardcode DISPLAY in ETC/ENVIRONMENT, but nothing changed - it affects the DISPLAY value where it is set (for users and processes), but not its visibility for processes run by the users.

Comment: Does this work for you? `env DISPLAY=:0 pgadmin3`

Comment: @MadMike: no, still the same error.

Comment: Maybe this answer works for you? http://askubuntu.com/a/28572/75166

Comment: @MadMike: No protocol specified. xhost: unable to open ":0" - so no luck. I will try to search more and focus on the "no protocol specified" part - this wasn't included in the questions/answers I already inspected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you `sudo`'d to the `postgres` user then tried to run Pgadmin from there.

Don't do that.

Run PgAdmin as your regular user, without `sudo`. You might need to create yourself a user account on the DB and/or edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow connections first, but once that's done you can use PgAdmin.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it's not recommended to assign postgres (superuser) a password under Linux, from security reasons. Was this a good advice, or not? If it was, then how to use pgadmin as postgres? Creating another superuser account with password?

Comment: @PavelV. I think that's a bit silly, personally. There's little meaningful difference between `peer` over a unix socket and using `md5` on connections restricted to localhost; if anything it's stronger since you need the password not just the correct login account. But you can use `peer` if you want; just add a `pg_ident.conf` entry allowing your username to log in as the `postgres` superuser. Personally: I'd just set a password on user `postgres` and tweak `pg_hba.conf` to allow `md5` logins. (Then again, I don't use PgAdmin so none of this applies to me normally).